# XPath to access a text after span

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework trying to access an element in a dynamic table. I am trying to click "TestAuto" text that will lead me to another page but I have great difficulties. I always struggle when "span" is in the code. Hope somebody can give me a pointer to create a proper xpath. Thanks.

The following is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<div class="col-sm-2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr data-tryxpath-element="0">
<td class="st-m3">
<span class="bongobongo">Name:</span>
TestAuto
<br>
<span class="bongoemail">Email:</span>
bongo@mail.com
<br>
<span class="bongotel">Phone:</span>
+1234567890
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr data-tryxpath-element="0">
<td class="st-m3">
<span class="bongobongo">Name:</span>
TestManual
<br>
<span class="bongoemail">Email:</span>
bongo123@mail.com
<br>
<span class="bongotel">Phone:</span>
+1234567891
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the following xpaths with negative results:

```
//div/table/tbody/tr/td[starts-with(@class,'table borderless mobile-list')] --> Useless anyway as it does not help to identify "TestAuto"
//div/table/tbody/tr/td//text()="TestAuto" --> Both tables are selected
//div/table/tbody/tr/td[normalize-space()='TestAuto'] --> Both tables are selected
//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following::text()="TestAuto" --> Both tables are selected
```

Answer (score 4):

Any text node following a `<span>` under the same parent:

```
//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()
```

Any text node with a value of `"TestAuto"` following a `<span>` under the same parent:

```
//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()[. = "TestAuto"]
```

Any *first* text node with a value of `"TestAuto"` following a `<span>` under the same parent:

```
//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()[1][. = "TestAuto"]
```

Any text node with a value of `"TestAuto"` *immediately* following a `<span>` under the same parent:

```
//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::node()[1][self::text() and . = "TestAuto"]
```

...in the first `<table>` under a `<div>` only (that's still multiple matches, if there are multiple such `<div>`s!):

```
//div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()[1][. = "TestAuto"]
```

...only the very first occurrence in the entire document (that's one match at maximum):

```
(//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()[1][. = "TestAuto"])[1]
```

**Note** You might have to use `normalize-space(.) = "TestAuto"` instead of `. = "TestAuto"`, in order to trim whitespace that might be in the source code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately when I tried the following, none of them was able to find the element. Is there something wrong?

Comment: //div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()[. = "TestAuto"]

//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()[1][. = "TestAuto"]

//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::node()[1][self::text() and . = "TestAuto"]

//div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()[1][. = "TestAuto"]

//div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/span/following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.) = "TestAuto"]

//div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.) = "TestAuto"]

Comment: All of these XPath expressions are tested and work against your sample.  I'm not surprised that your actual data is different and that "copy and paste" does not work. The reason why I gave so many examples is so that you can better understand how XPath works and figure out the correct expression on your own.

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you're trying to do. For 2 days I have been trying all kinds of combinations without any success. Theoretically, I believe '//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span[@class="bongobongo"]/following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.)="Test Auto"]' should work. Tested using Try XPath, it highlighted 2 tables that I could not understand why. When using Robot Framework, it complained xpath was not found.

Comment: Using my actual xpath '//div/table/tbody/tr/td/span[@class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"]', up to this level I have no problem detecting 2 spans from 2 different tables. This is not a problem. The moment I added '/following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.)="Test Auto"]' nothing has been found even though "Test Auto" is right after the span.

Comment: Do other tools find something with the same HTML and same XPath? If yes, it could indicate that robot framework does not support finding text nodes. I mean, what happens if you search for just *any* text node in Robot Framework?

Comment: Robot framework has no issue with normal text node without "span" getting in the way.  Xpath such as //button[contains(text(), "Save")] has no issue at all. The problem is when I tried to "navigate" over a "span" to get the text after "span" using "following-sibling". Maybe "following-sibling" doesn't work in robot framework.

Comment: Using tool such as Try Xpath seems to be able to find the text after "span". The counter is correct but it's highlighting two tables instead of highlighting at the text in one of the tables. So, I am equally confused by this tool as well. Using robot framework totally failed to locate the element.

Comment: Maybe robot framework likes to return *elements* only? Text nodes aren't elements. (I explained the reason why there can be multiple matches in my answer, too.)

Comment: Yeah, you did but xpath with '= "TestAuto"' is very specific and I have made sure there is no other "TestAuto" in the page but it's highlighting a table without "TestAuto" that does not make any sense for me. From the code given above, it's highlighting the table with "TestManual" as well.

Comment: What does the line that calls the XPath look like? Could it be you are using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."))`?

Comment: It could be something like: Page Should Contain Element | //div/table/tbody/tr/td/span[@class="bongobongo"]/following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.)="Test Auto"]

Comment: I actually don't use "|". It's for you to easily see that there is a separator between the Robot Framework keyword and the xpath. In real life, I use tab.

Comment: It could be: Click Element | //div/table/tbody/tr/td/span[@class="bongobongo"]/following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.)="Test Auto"] if I want to click the xpath.

Comment: This is all well and nice, but if robot framework (read the source code, it's open source after all!) uses `driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."))` or something like that to execute your XPaths then it won't work. As I said, text nodes are not elements.

Comment: Thanks, Tomalak. Looks like I can't use this method based on your info :(

Comment: Don't base anything on my info, I don't know robot framework. Read the source code. It can't be very hard to find. It certainly takes less time than the days you have put into trying random stuff. Only good things can come from that: 1) You understand robot framework better. 2) You will know for sure why it works the way it does. 3) You might find an alternative function that you can use. Finally: Robot Framework can be extended with custom code. You might have to do that. Having read some of the source code will help.